# MERN Stack - Ordering Table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So, I've battled with this for several hours and for the life of me cannot figure out how to simply order the list items in the table. The data is being pulled from a MongoDB using Axios.

**I am using MongoDB Express React and NodeJS**

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/MattGHicks/BrailleWorks-App

Any help would be much appreciated.

I want the project to sort by "*workorder_po*" automatically on load of the "*workorders-list*" compenent.

**Below is the workorders-list.component.js file.**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


const WorkOrder = props => (
    <tr>
        <td className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.workorder.workorder_po}</td>
        <td className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.workorder.workorder_name}</td>
        <td className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.workorder.workorder_status}</td>
        <td className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.workorder.workorder_shippingFrom}</td>
        <td className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.workorder.workorder_completionDate}</td>
        <td>
            <Link className="btn btn-sm btn-primary" to={"/edit/"+props.workorder._id}>Edit</Link>
            <Link className="btn btn-sm btn-danger" to={"/remove/"+props.workorder._id}>Remove</Link>
            <a className={props.workorder.workorder_completed ? 'btn btn-sm btn-info' : 'invisible'} href={"https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?tRef=fullpage&tLc=2&text28777=&tLabels="+props.workorder.workorder_tracking+"%2C" } target="_blank">Tracking</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
);


export default class WorkOrdersList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {workorders: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://matthicksdev.com:4000/workorders/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({workorders: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get('http://matthicksdev.com:4000/workorders/')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({workorders: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })   
    }

    workorderList() {
        return this.state.workorders.map(function(currentWorkOrder, i) {
            return <WorkOrder workorder={currentWorkOrder} key={i} />;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Work Order Status List</h3>
                <table className="table table-sm table-striped table-dark" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Job ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Shipping From</th>
                            <th>Completion/Ship Date</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.workorderList() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to try material-ui tables? There are some default options which includes sort in certain cols.

Comment: Thanks for the source. I'm just not wrapping my head around how exactly I would implement it on this project. I think I may try to dive into Material and see if I can get something going.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a matter of adding ".sort({ workorder_po: -1 });" onto my route in the 'server.js' file.

Got it!

```
workorderRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    WorkOrder.find(function(err, workorders) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(workorders);
        }
    }).sort({ workorder_po: -1 });
});
```